# How to deny access to a url within htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

How can I deny direct access to a URL through `.htaccess` file?

The URL for example is

```
www.example.com/course/reset-password
```

The file is located within a `course` folder and the alternative and all files in that folder can allow direct access with exception of `reset-password.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `corse/.htacccess` you can have just this rule to block access:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /reset-password [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to deny access to a specific *file* (as opposed to a URL) then consider using mod_authz_core (Apache 2.4) instead of mod_rewrite. For example:

```
<Files "reset-password.php">
Require all denied
</Files>
```

This has less chance of being overridden than mod_rewrite.